# How can I align 3 divs side by side?

Tags: css, html

I have 3 div's, 200px,300px and 200px how can I align them side by side, all the examples I have seen only include 2. I have Div1,Div2 working correctly but Div3 for some reason slides under Div1 lie this picture
[image]

This is my code

```
<div style=" border-right:1px solid black; width:200px; float:left; position:relative; ">
 //div1
 </div>

  <div style=" border-right:1px solid black; width:300px; padding:10px;float:left; position:relative;">
    //div2
  </div>
 
<div style=" float: left; width: 200px;position:relative">
//div3
 </div>
```

The **Div1** has the shorter content on it, how can I make the border to the right as long as the border in **Div2**?

Comment: Your code is perfectly *OK*. Besides you need to have one wrapper div with width > ( 200+300+200+ Any padding or margin you have in div )

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**All the elements in one line**

Wrap the `div` elements in a wrapper:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="first">first</div>
  <div id="second">second</div>
  <div id="third">third</div>
</div>
```

Then set the width of the wrapper, and float all three `div`s:

```
#wrapper {
  width:700px;
  clear:both;
}
#first {
  background-color:red;
  width:200px;
  float:left;
}
#second {
  background-color:blue;
  width:300px;
  float:left;
}
#third {
  background-color:#bada55;
  width:200px;
  float:left;
}
```

Also, use IDs and/or classes, and keep the CSS separate from the HTML.  This makes the code easier to read and maintain.

The [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mathieujonson/pvktL/).

**All elements in one line, same height**

To accomplish the "same height" part, you can use `display:table`, `display:table-row`, and `display:table-cell` to get matching heights.  It uses an extra div, so the HTML looks like:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="row">
    <div id="first">first</div>
    <div id="second">second<br><br></div>
    <div id="third">third</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The floats can then be removed, so the CSS looks like:

```
#wrapper {
  display:table;
  width:700px;
}
#row {
  display:table-row;
}
#first {
  display:table-cell;
  background-color:red;
  width:200px;
}
#second {
  display:table-cell;
  background-color:blue;
  width:300px;
}
#third {
  display:table-cell;
  background-color:#bada55;
  width:200px;
}
```

The [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mathieujonson/EuqZV/).

**The Flexbox Way**

If you're only supporting newer browsers (IE 10 and up), Flexbox is another good choice.  Make sure to prefix for better support.  More on the prefixes can be found [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

**The HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="first">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
  <div class="second">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil ratione rerum deserunt reiciendis numquam fugit dolor eligendi fuga sit. Hic, tempore. Error, temporibus possimus deserunt quisquam rerum dolor quam natus.Fugiat nam recusandae doloribus culpa obcaecati facere eligendi consectetur cum eveniet quod et, eum, libero esse voluptates. Ut commodi consequuntur eligendi doloremque deserunt modi animi explicabo aperiam, non, quas qui!</div>
  <div class="third">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet obcaecati, rem. Ullam quia quae, ad, unde saepe velit incidunt, aliquid eum facere obcaecati molestiae? Repellendus tempore magnam facere, sint similique!</div>
</div>
```

**The CSS**

```
.container {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
}
.container > div {
  margin:10px;
  background-color:#bada55;
}
.first, .third {
  width:200px;
}
.second {
  width:300px;
}
```

The [Codepen](http://codepen.io/mathieujonson/pen/dGRVbQ).

**The Grid Way**

You can accomplish this with [grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) now, too, though [browser support](https://caniuse.com/#search=grid) might be an issue if you're supporting older browsers.  It's the same HTML as with the flexbox example, with just different CSS:

**The CSS**

```
.container {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
  width:700px;
}
.container > div {
  background-color:#bada55;
}
.first, .third {
  width:200px;
}
.second {
  width:300px;
}
```

The [codepen](https://codepen.io/mathieujonson/pen/MrWxyE).

Comment: @user1949387 I just noticed the "making same height" part of the question.  I updated the answer to include a way that meets both requirements.  Glad it works, and thanks for the accept!

Answer (score 1):

The HTML code is

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="first">first</div>
  <div id="second">second</div>
  <div id="third">third</div>
</div>
```

The CSS will be

```
#wrapper {
  display:table;
  width:100%;
}
#row {
  display:table-row;
}
#first {
  display:table-cell;
  background-color:red;
  width:33%;
}
#second {
  display:table-cell;
  background-color:blue;
  width:33%;
}
#third {
  display:table-cell;
  background-color:#bada55;
  width:34%;
}
```

This code will workup towards responsive layout as it will resize the

```
<div>
```

according to device width. 
Even one can silent anyone

```
<div>
```

as

```
<!--<div id="third">third</div> -->
```

and can use rest two for two

```
<div>
```

side by side.