# aligning 2 divs next to each other

Tags: html, css

I have 2 section on a home page, both with a picture and some text. I want to get the picture and the text of the top section next to each other (picture on left and text on the right). And then in the bottom section the text on the left and the picture to the right of the text.

**Snippet**

```css
.alignnone {
  width: 20%;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 13px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.first {}

.button {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #43dbdb;
  margin: 1%;
  float: left;
}

.drop {
  width: 30% !important;
  border: none;
  padding: 0%;
  float: right;
}

.top {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 2%;
}

.bottom {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  padding: 2%;
}

#content {
  background-color: #D7DBDD;
  background-size: 90%;
  padding: 6%;
  margin: -2%;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
  <img src="https://privatechefanna.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/IMG_3695.jpg" height="99" width="99" alt="Anna" class="alignnone " />
  <h3>ABOUT ME</h3>
  <p class="first ">.....</p>
</div>
<div class="bottom">
  <img src="https://privatechefanna.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/IMG_3713.jpg" height="99" width="99" alt="Anna" class="drop" />
  <h3>WHAT I DO</h3>
  <p class="second">.....</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Show your effort and your code?

Comment: Have you search for similar question here on SO? Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20179154/html-and-css-how-can-i-align-3-divs-side-by-side) question.

Comment: Yes, I have. Still stuck though. I am a proper noob when it comes to coding, so it's a constant learning curve and struggle ;-)

Comment: Are you able to edit the html or just the css?

Answer (score 0):

Is [this](https://codepen.io/abidishajia/pen/QQWBWB) (created a codepen) something you are looking for?

```
<div class="top">
<div class="clearfix">
<img class="img1" src="https://privatechefanna.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/IMG_3713.jpg" width="99" height="99">
<h3>ABOUT ME</h3>
  <p class="first ">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum...</p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="bottom">
<div class="clearfix">
<img class="img2" src="https://privatechefanna.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/IMG_3713.jpg" width="99" height="99">
<h3>WHAT I DO</h3>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum...</p></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.drop {
  width: 30% !important;
  border: none;
  padding: 0%;
}

.top {
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 2%;
}

.bottom {
  vertical-align: bottom;
  padding: 2%;
}
.clearfix {
    overflow: auto;
}

.img2 {
    float: right;
    margin-left: 15px;
}

.img1{
  float: left;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
```